# Why should you put (GameObject) before Instantiate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this script that creates an instance of a cannon ball and then adds force to it when you click left mouse button.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CannonControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cannonBall;
    public GameObject cannonBallSpawn;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            GameObject cannonBallClone = Instantiate(cannonBall, cannonBallSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            cannonBallClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(cannonBallSpawn.transform.forward * 2000); 
        }
    }
}
```

In many tutorials people would use **(GameObject)Instantiate**:

```
GameObject cannonBallClone = (GameObject)Instantiate(cannonBall, cannonBallSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

I tried it both ways and don't see the difference. I also couldn't find what **(GameObject)** really does.

Which one should I use and why?

Comment: It's a casting instruction used when the coder knows more about the type of an object than the compiler (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**you don't need to**

your example is maybe from an older Unity version where `Instantiate` returned always `Object` and you had to [**type cast via `(GameObject)` explicitely**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions) or someone who just didn't know better ;)

[`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) is also available as a [**generic**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) (see bottom part of the page)

```
public static T Instantiate<T>(T original);
```

and returns the same type as the given prefab ... in your case it already **is** a `GameObject`.

Note that even in their own example (at the bottom) the additional `<Missile>` is redundant since the parameter already is a `Missile` and defines `T` for this call

You can simply call

```
GameObject cannonBallClone = Instantiate(cannonBall, cannonBallSpawn.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

---

This said as an additional hint: You could get rid of the `GetComponent` call if you make the prefab field of the correct type right away

```
public Rigidbody cannonBall;
public Transform cannonBallSpawn;
```

this makes also sure you can only reference an Object/Prefab that actually **has** the required component attached. And then you can a bit shorter call

```
// will now return a Rigidbody instead
var cannonBallClone = Instantiate(cannonBall, cannonBallSpawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
cannonBallClone.AddForce(cannonBallSpawn.forward * 2000);
```